# JQUERY: using html on click on jquery function with parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm stuck in a jquery problem where i want to pass parameters in jquery function on HTML `onclick` event.

HTML:

```
 <p><a href="#" class='cls1' onclick='func1("a1")'>Anchor1</a></p>
 <div><a href="#" class='cls1' onclick='func1("a2")'>Anchor2</a><div>
 <span><a href="#" class='cls1' onclick='func1("a3")'>Anchor3</a></span>
```

JQUERY:

```
 function func1(var param)
 {
    var parnt = $(this).parent(); // i want to get parent, this only gives [object object]
    alert('Parent:'+parnt+' param:'+param) //alert parnt and param
    return false;
 }
```

I know its something easy, but i just cant find the right direction to move on. Any Guidance is appreciated heartly. 
Thank you.

Comment: This is just a simpler version of what i am trying to do..

Comment: do the variables a1,a2,a3 exist in the global scope? if yes, then it will work. if they are defined in the jquery global function they are not global, and it wont work

Comment: a1, a2, arent' the javascript variables they are only strings... sorry for that.. will edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that "this" has no reference to the object being passed. A workaround woud be to do:

```
onclick='func1(this,"a1")'
```

and change function to:

```
 function func1(obj,param)
 {
    var parnt = $(obj).parent();
    alert('Parent:'+parnt+' param:'+param) //alert parnt and param
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: why do i have to give an extra `this` arguement while i have provided explicitly `this` on my function itself. Cud you please make it a bit descriptive for me?

Comment: @Geniusintrouble: because `this` has different meanings in the two contexts; if you want, have a look at this page, expecially under the "Referring" section: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html
It explains why your solution won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Alert box can only alert Strings. If you want to see the object, use `console.log()`. It would work in all browsers except IE.
Also get rid of the 'var' in

```
function func1(var param){

}
```

And if you want to bind a function to a click event, use `on()`

Comment: this aint' what i was asking for.. anyway thx for the concern

Comment: i tried console.log which gives `Parent:[object Object] param:hello`

Comment: try put them into two console.log statements. I think strings and objects don't go well in the same console.log statement.

Answer (score 2):

you get object in parent method result because you need to specify what attribute you want to access:

```
$(".cls1").on("click", function(){

    var clickedID = $(this).attr("id"); // result :  "a1 or a2 or a3"

    var parentTag = $(this).parent().get(0).tagName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" class='cls1' onclick="func1(\'' + a1 + '\')">Anchor1</a></p>
 <div><a href="#" class='cls1' onclick="func1(\'' +a2+ '\')">Anchor2</a><div>
 <span><a href="#" class='cls1' onclick="func1(\'' + a3 + '\')">Anchor3</a></span>
```

call function like this..

```
function func1(param)
 {
    var parnt = $(param).parent(); // i want to get parent, this only gives [object object]
    alert('Parent:'+parnt+' param:'+param) //alert parnt and param
    return false;
 }
```

you have to use escape characters when you pass string like this.. `(\'' + a1 + '\')`

Comment: a1, a2, arent' variables they are simply strings that i want to pass as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can get rid of onclick attributes in your HTML and bind event handling in JS;
2. You can assign one event handler to handle all elements, and determine which element has been clicked by analysing "this" variable.
3. Use console.log and console.dir to get a better idea of what your variables are.
4. Read documentation and tutorials - what you are doing is very trivial and there's been lots of stuff written about it: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/ + http://justfuckinggoogleit.com/
5. Get to grips with event propagation models

I could have written the code for you, but I think it's important you learn yourself. Good luck!